# Python: annotation for object types in method

Tags: python, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check arguments of the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247833/how-to-check-arguments-of-the-function)

Probably this is duplicated question.. sorry for that..

Let's look at the example below:

```py
class ClassA(object):
     pass
class ClassB(object):
     pass

def foo(a, b):
    if not isinstance(a, ClassA):
         raise ValueError("1st agrument should be instance of ClassA")
    if not isinstance(b, ClassB):
         raise ValueError("2nd agrument should be instance of ClassB")
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

Is there any annotation in 2.7 python or something in `__future__` module to annotate method to check input variables ?

Writing those `if not isinstance` makes me really mad :D

Comment: You could probably tailor [this solution](http://mrkschan.blogspot.com/2010/08/python-decorator-for-input-validation.html) to your needs.

Comment: I'm not sure type checking is a very pythonic thing to do.

Comment: Having said that, [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/454322-type-checking-decorator/) might work for you.

Comment: @Eric If you post this solution as an answer I will accept that response as solution of my problem

Comment: Python annotations are *not* type declarations. They are just a way to document the signature of the function, and provide a way to access it easily from code. Anyway, before starting to type check everything please think if you can solve your problem with a bit of duck typing. Because that's what python users would expect.

Comment: @Bakuriu I love strict object typisation  - like in Java.. for me this is only weakness of Python and also it's Power..

Comment: Then why do you want to write in python? Writing python as it was Java will only lead to bad and unefficient code.

Comment: @Bakuriu Because I love Django :) and prefer than PHP :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built in way to define argument types for functions - this is partly by design - rather than getting an error of "classA expected" when passing a classB, you get an error while looking up an attribute. You could then define this attribute on classB, and the function would work with a type it wasn't originally designed for.

Having size that, [here is an example of how to write the decorator you're after](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/454322-type-checking-decorator/).